# Django model with 3 many to many fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these models

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField()
    ph_number = models.CharField()

class ExamPaper(models.Model):
    paper_name = models.CharField()
    paper_subject = models.CharField()

class Questions(models.Model):
    paper = models.ManyToManyField(ExamPaper, related_name='question_set')
    question_num = models.IntegerField()
    question_text = models.TextField()
```

Now I want to store the results of each question by each user for each paper. Paper will have multiple questions and a question may also belong to multiple papers. User may give multiple papers and multiple questions.

I want mysql table to have user, paper and question to define primary key taken all together and two more fields 'marks' and 'result'. I'm not able to understand how to do this in django models. Will this work:

```
class Result(models.Model):
     user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
     paper = models.ManyToManyField(ExamPaper)
     question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
     marks = models.IntegerField()
     result = models.CharField()
```

Please anyone can anyone explain?

Comment: It would be better to use the default `id` field as `Result`'s primary key. Naming could be better as well; `Questions` should be `Question` (since one record is one question) and having a field `result` in `Result` is confusing, but I can't suggest something better since I have no idea what `marks` and `result` represent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use one-to-many ([ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)) relationships instead of many-to-many:

```
class Result(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     paper = models.ForeignKey(ExamPaper)
     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
     marks = models.IntegerField()
     result = models.CharField()

     class Meta:
         unique_together = (("user", "paper", "question"), )
```

If a question can appear only on one exam paper, then Question.paper should also be a `ForeignKey` and you could remove the `paper` field from `Result`.

Comment: Also, you probably don't need the `paper` field either, because you can access that by doing `result.question.paper`, unless of course the `paper` field in the `Result` will not be the same for the `paper` field in `Question` related to the `Result`, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Bryce: Can't do that because `result.question.paper` is a many-to-many relationship. I.e. a question can appear in multiple papers. I think this is for a system where exams contain a set of questions randomly chosen from a pool, so each student's exam is different, discouraging cheating.

Comment: I got exactly the db schema I was looking for by changing manytomany fields to foreignkey fields. Thanks. Actually question can appear in multiple papers and hence I need user, paper and question unique combined together. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Maybe I should have downvoted, then, since that makes this a wrong answer, per OP's comment?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you probably want the unique_together option for the _meta class.  See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#unique-together

EDIT:  Looks like django requires at least one primary key field.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: but it doesn't allow to use unique_together with ManyToManyFields

Comment: You shouldn't use `ManyToMany` in `Result`. You don't have one result for a set of user, a set of questions, and set of results... and if you do, I think you need to refactor your schema, because things will get **very** painful when writing queries.